# How do you use the built in Java tts?

Tags: java, accessibility, speech-synthesis

I am trying to use the java built in speech however whenever I try to use it it gives me a null pointer exception when I call synth.allocate. I have looked at examples online but I still get the same error and I can't see what I'm doing wrong

```
JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(
                    new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));

                synth.allocate();
                synth.resume();

                synth.speakPlainText("Hello, world!", null);

                synth.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);

                synth.deallocate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Q: What makes you think there *is* a "built in Java TTS" (Text-to-Speech)???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your system doesn't have a synthesizer for Locale.ENGLISH installed.  This in turn would cause Central.createSynthesizer() to return null, which would cause the null pointer exception at synth.allocate().

You may want to call Central.availableSynthesizers() to find what synthesizers are installed on your system, before you call Central.createSynthesizer().

Also, as a quick test, you might try Locale.US instead of Locale.ENGLISH and see whether that works...it's just a guess.

I see that FreeTTS (http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) is described as an implementation of the Java Speech interface.  Installing that might help.

Comment: Thanks you were right there were no synthesizers installed at all is there a way to make or install one that you know of?

Comment: It looks like [freeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#download_and_install) provides a US English synthesizer, but I haven't tried that out.